# Read excel null/blank values

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to read excel null/blank values. 
I have looked into hundreds of solutions and either I am implementing it wrong or it just does not seem to work and results in Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'

This is one of the last codes I tried.(Since I was trying to put NA in all the null cells)

```
for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    string natext = xlRange.Value2[rowCount, colCount];
    if (natext == null)
    {
        natext = "NA";
    }
```

Any ideas that can help me with some examples?

> If the click the details it shows:
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message=Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
>   reference   Source=
>   StackTrace:

Answer (score 4):

First, the Excel object model is really weird. `Value2` returns an `object`, and that object can be of all sorts of different types. If `xlRange` is a cell, then it returns the value of that cell, which could be a `string` or a `double` or something else. If `xlRange` is multiple cells then that `object` is an array of values. And then each of those values is an `object`. For each value you don't know if it's a `string` or a `double` or something else.

That's not fun to deal with. It's actually really, really bad. C# is a strongly-typed language, which means that you know what type everything is and you don't have to guess. Excel Interop takes that away from you and says, "Here's an object. It could be anything or lots of things that could each be anything. Figure it out. Good luck."

Instead of getting the `Value2` property of the range and then looping through the array, it's much easier to deal with the cells in the range instead.

Given that `excelRange` is a `Range` of cells:

```
for (var row = 1; row <= excelRange.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for (var column = 1; row <= excelRange.Columns.Count; row++)
    {
        var cellText = excelRange[row, column].Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

This does two things. First, you're looking at one cell at a time. Second, you're using the `Text` property. The `Text` property *should* always be a `string` so you could just do this and it would almost certainly work:

```
string cellText = excelRange.Cells[row, column].Text;
```

It's just that the object model returns `dynamic`, so even though it is a `string`, the possibility is left open that maybe it won't be.

---

My strong recommendation - and I think most developers would agree - is to abandon Excel Interop and run from it, and use a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) instead. There are tons of examples.

Excel Interop works by actually starting an instance of Excel and giving you access to the clunky VBA object model. It's evil. Chances are that if you open your task manager right now you'll see several extra instances of Excel open that you didn't expect to see. Fixing that is a whole separate frustrating problem.

For some years Excel files have just been collections of XML documents, and EPPlus helps you to work with them as documents, but providing all sorts of helper methods so that you can interact with sheets, ranges, cells, and so forth. Try it. Trust me, you'll never look back.

Here's an example after adding the [EPPlus Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/):

```
var pathToYourExcelWorkbook = @"c:\somepath\document.xlsx";
using (var workbookPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(pathToYourExcelWorkbook)))
{
    var workbook = workbookPackage.Workbook;
    var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1]; // 1-based, or use the name.
    for (var row = 1; row <= 10; row++)
    {
        for (var column = 1; column <= 10; column++)
        {
            var cellText = sheet.Cells[row, column].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

It's awesome. No starting or closing an application - you're just reading from a file. No weird COM objects. And the objects are all strongly-typed. The `Text` property returns a `string`.

Comment: Thank you Scott!  Really appreciate the explanation and the fact that you steered me in a better/different direction. There is a small issue with EEplus that I am experiencing. Not sure if that that is a separate thread or within this one. The last line of the EEplus output gets truncated. As if it is half a line of output and not complete. Any ideas why?

Comment: I looked into it, in more detail and all the lines write perfect but at 46th row (out of 50 rows in my xl file) it somehow truncates writing to my output text file. I even have dummy console.writelines on each pass of my FOR loop and all the logic seems perfect. What gives? :)

Comment: Then I reduced the number of rows in my xl spreadsheet to 45 and now it cuts out at 41 lines. Has something to do with last 4 lines of output to my cef/txt file. hmm

Comment: Eurika!  the problems I was having was streamwriter related and it was fixed with sw.Flush();